# Remove middle initials from full name such as (A or H.)

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do you remove the middle initials from the full name? By creating a custom function?

I want to convert `FullName` to `FullNameWithoutInitials`:

| FullName | FullNameWithoutInitials |
| --- | --- |
| John A Smith | John Smith |
| John B. Smith | John Smith |
| John Smith C | John Smith |
| John Smith Z. | John Smith |

How do I remove any words equal to 1 (with or without a dot) character such as (A or A.) from a string?

Thank you!

Comment: This is not a task for SQL Server; simply put. It's, honestly, one of the *worst* tools to even consider trying to achieve this in. This is also relevant reading: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: I got no choice. :/ 
This must be done in MS SQL.

Comment: I would do this as a ONE TIME script ro **properly** set up your data set .. And add the fields "FirstName", "LastName" and "MiddleInitial" That way you can just `SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, " ", Lastname) ... `  Or Just FirstName => *"Hello FirstName!!"*

Comment: Names are not a solved problem. This is a huge can of worms you're about to open.

Comment: *I got no choice*  --  I would seriously talk to management or whoever you need to talk to .. You need to properly set up your data .. And you are currently suffering from the [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You are correct, you do have no choice; you have no choice but to not be able to achieve this is T-SQL. Any attempt you make would very likely make some truly *awful* assumptions. If you need to be able to identify a person's first, middle and last names, you need to store those in 3 columns (perhaps called `FirstName`, `MiddleNames` and `LastName`). Then you can easily identify which is which. There is only a few guaranteed ways of identifying what a person's actual name(s) are; asking them or consulting an official document are a couple.

Comment: I think I can solve this problem by removing words between spaces having LEN of 2 or 1.

Comment: As I mention in the below answer, assuming someone's name most be >= 3 characters long is a very foolish assumption, @Montreal . There is no requirement someone's name can't be 1 or 2 characters long.

Comment: There's all sorts of cases where the name can consist of parts with 2 letters, like `XXX de YYY` without being an initial. I'm quite sure this is what Joel Coehoorn meant.

Comment: @Montreal: then what would happen to a name like `Oscar de la Hoya` ? Would you remove "de" and "la" as "middle initials" , turning his name in `Oscar Hoya` ?? As Joel Coehoorn said in his comment - *huge can of worms* you're about to open here! Think about it..... long and hard....

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for pointing it out, I have modified the question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the following solution.

Obviously, it cannot take care of all possible scenarios with names.

It using XML and XQuery to *tokenize* **FullName** column.

The XPath predicate `[string-length() gt 2]` is removing any words less than or equal to 2 chars.

**SQL #1**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, FullName VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tbl (FullName) VALUES
('John A Smith'),
('John B. Smith'),
('John Smith C'),
('John Smith Z.'),
('Nguyen H. NG');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @separator CHAR(1) = SPACE(1);

SELECT t.* 
    , c.query('data(/root/r[string-length() gt 2])').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(FullName, @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**SQL #2**

First, removing a dot. After that removing just a single letter words.

```
SELECT t.* 
    , c.query('data(/root/r[string-length() gt 1])').value('text()[1]', 'VARCHAR(30)') AS Result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
      REPLACE(REPLACE(FullName,'.',@separator), @separator, ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
      ']]></r></root>' AS XML)) AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

| ID | FullName | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John A Smith | John Smith |
| 2 | John B. Smith | John Smith |
| 3 | John Smith C | John Smith |
| 4 | John Smith Z. | John Smith |
| 5 | Nguyen H. NG | Nguyen NG |

Comment: What about someone called [Ng Yong Li](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ng_Yong_Li)?

Comment: The OP asked to keep words for LEN(name) > 2. And I am not looking for a universal solution.

Comment: Which is a foolish assumption; people's names don't have to be >= 3 characters long.

Comment: I completely concur

Comment: Thank you @YitzhakKhabinsky so much!
I think I am unitentionally descriminating against the vietnamese names such as NG.
Can we choose to remove [a-zA-Z] words that are shorter than 2 characters and remove those with or without a period.
Only remove A or A. ... Z or Z.
Keep the rest?

Comment: ('Nguyen H. NG') removes both.

Comment: Please check SQL #2

Comment: Click the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted"

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky can you please convert this to a custom function? :)